# Using Mean Value Theorem to prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that for all $0\lt a,b \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ with $a\lt b$
>
> $$\lvert \tan^{-1}(a)-\tan^{-1}(b)\rvert \lt \lvert a-b\rvert$$

**My attempt:**

Let $f(x)= \tan^{-1}(x)$

$\tan(x)\ \text{is continuous and differentiable on the interval so by the MVT,} $

$$\lvert \tan(b)-\tan(a) \rvert= \lvert b-a\rvert.f'(c)$$

$$f'(c)= \frac{1}{1+c^2}\lt \frac{1}{1+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}\lt1$$

Therefore we have,

$$\lvert \tan(a)-\tan(b) \rvert= \lvert a-b\rvert.f'(c)\lt1$$

Because $\lvert a-b\rvert= \lvert b -a\rvert$

Would this be correct?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite see how, the reciprocal of tan is cot and the derivative of cot is -cosec$^2$(x)

Comment: $f'(c)$ need not be $\le 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\tan^{-1}$, and why doesn't it appear in your attempt? (usually, $\tan^{-1}$ is the arctan function)

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ or $\arctan x$? These are very different things (and I hate that the notation $\tan^{-1}$ is used for this very reason).

Comment: Is it $\arctan$ or $\tan$?

Comment: This is the confusion I am having myself! This was a past exam paper and this was exactly how it is written. I have myself assumed that it is not arctan however I cannot be sure

Comment: When in doubt, replace $\operatorname{trig}^{-1}$ with $\operatorname{arctrig}$. It will make things so much less confusing for you. It is terrible notation that math teachers everywhere should be derided for for using and perpetuating.

Comment: I see! I will update my attempt now

Comment: Is the updated version correct? I can see from Paul's comment that it definitely must be $\arctan(x)$

Comment: A better problem would be to show that if $a<b$ then $\arctan b- \arctan a < b-a,$ with no other restrictions on $a,b.$ (Restricting to $a,b<\pi/2$ is weird)

Comment: I too feel this way. Is my edited attempt correct? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some sure that $\tan^{-1}a$ denotes that $\arctan a$ (otherwise, this doesn't hold, because you can let $a=b=\frac { pi}4$.

Therefore, $|\arctan a - \arctan b| = \frac{1}{1+\xi^2} |a-b| < |a-b|,$ where $\xi \in (a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks Paul, is my edited version correct?

Comment: @THISISIT453 There exists some small mistakes still.